# Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в данном случае перед кавычками после слова "сотрудников", если в кавычках указано название приказа?

> С опубликованным приказом, стимулирующим сотрудников(,) "Приказ по организации №22" все были ознакомлены.

"Приказ по организации №22" - название приказа.

Comment: А зачем в этом предложении слово "опубликованным"? Мне кажется, лучше так: С "Приказом по организации №22", стимулирующим сотрудников, все были ознакомлены.

Answer (score 2):

Предложение лучше перестроить:

**С опубликованным  "Приказом по организации №22", стимулирующим сотрудников, все были ознакомлены.**

Answer (score 0):

С сохранением в этой фразе двух *приказов* второй следует обособить как уточнение или титул. Но это лучше сделать скобками. Оборот внутри предложения необходимо закрыть запятой.

С опубликованным приказом, стимулирующим сотрудников (Приказ по организации №22), все были ознакомлены.

Answer (score 0):

Все плохо. Исходная формулировка содержит два определения "стимулирущий" и "опубликованный", которые относятся к приказу, а само слово "приказ" используется дважды. В результате - косноязычие, очень тяжело воспринимается фраза. Запятая-то нужна, без неё вообще нет никакой возможности понять грамматику фразы, но с запятой то, что вы называете "названием" еще как-то тянет на роль несогласованного приложения.

Стилистическая же проблема (перерастающая в грамматическую) в том, что два определения ну никак не получаются однородными. 
Совершенно верно заметили, что слово "опубликованный" не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки. Коли уж все ознакомлены, то ясно что он опубликован.
А если уж это так важно, но сообщите дату "опубликования", всё станет ясно.
И разберитесь, пишете ли вы деловым стилем, художественным или же это обычный бытовой разговор.

В соответствии с этим несколько вариантов правки.

"***Со стимулирующим сотрудников "Приказом по организации №22" все были  ознакомлены***. 
или
***"Все были  ознакомлены со стимулирующим сотрудников "Приказом по организации №22"***. 
Это обычный разговорно-бытовой стиль.

"***Со стимулирующим сотрудников "Приказом по организации №22" (опубликован 11.11,2011) все были ознакомлены*** - здесь смысловой акцент на "все", но это не очень характерно для делового стиля.

Поэтому лучше
"***Все (сотрудники) были ознакомлены со стимулирующим приказом (Приказ №22 от 11.11.2011 по "Обществу защиты правописания")***

или

"***Все были ознакомлены со стимулирующим сотрудников приказом (Приказ №22 по "Обществу защиты правописания" от 11.11.2011  "О дополнительных мерах стимуляции сотрудников")***.

Вот последний вариант (с заменой на реальные названия), пожалуй, ближе всего к идеалу. Остается только слово "Все" нагрузить нужным смыслом. "Все заинтересованные", "Все подчиненные", "все работники""...

Comment: Большое спасибо!